# How to initialize the starting path in Qt treeview?

Tags: qt, path, initialization, dir, qtreeview

I want to initialize the starting path in Qt treeview to the user home on Linux Ubuntu.

[image]

I tried this code but it does not work.

```
QString sPath = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx";
dirmodel = new QFileSystemModel(this);
dirmodel->setFilter(QDir::NoDotAndDotDot | QDir::AllDirs);
dirmodel->setRootPath(sPath);
ui->treeView->setModel(dirmodel);
```

- I have tested the sPath :

  1. `/home/<username>`
  2. `${HOME}`
  3. `/home/casper/Music`

No one works. =[

How to solve this?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: That should work. What result do you get?

Comment: @this.lau_ - Which sPath do you mean? 1,2 or 3? I just get the path "/"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the model is loaded, I think you need to call `setRootIndex` on the tree widget:

```
ui->treeView->setRootIndex(dirmodel->index("/home/casper"));
```

Or for any home directory (also works on Windows, OSX, etc.):

```
ui->treeView->setRootIndex(dirmodel->index(QDir::homePath()));
```

Comment: When the user name is not "casper", will this method works? Thanks

Comment: @CasperLi, if you want the home directory specifically, you can use `QDir::homePath()`. I've updated my answer with an example.